# Ruby alternative to Service Layer

Tags: ruby

I am writing a Ruby on Rails app. which will use a 3rd party to do a webservice call or a rest call or some sort of call.  I am not sold on which 3rd party I am going to use so I want to isolate this in some sort of facade.

If I was doing this in .NET, I would isolate this functionality in a service that I inject into the controller.  This means I can easily mock out the service in order to make it testable but in ruby, it is much easier to mock things so I don't think I need this level of indirection and de-coupling that I would need in a static application.

This feels very un-ruby-like and I would like to hear how more experienced ruby developers approach this problem of isolating the code to make it mockable and testable and also give me the option to swap which 3rd party provider I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ruby-like version of "I would isolate this functionality in a service that I inject into the controller" would be something like "I would write this as a ruby module that I include in my class"

Answer (score 1):

If it is a RESTful webservice, I would do this in a model that inherits from [ActiveResource::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html).  It should be relatively easy to mock this out as well for testing purposes.